# C++ template argument deduction/substitution failed:

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, lambda, divide-and-conquer

I am quite new to C++ and I am experiencing some of its features. In particular, I would like to implement a generic **Divide and Conquer** procedure that takes as parameter the 'functional code' to solve the problem. Actually what I have in mind is that 'Divide and Conquer' is a higher order function taking as parameters:

- a function `basecase()` to test whether the we reached the base case
- a function `solvecase()` to solve the base case
- a function `divide()` to split the problem in two subproblems
- a function `conquer()` that takes to partial solutions and builds one solution out of the two.

To do this, I used **templates**: in particular, type `A` is the type of the input problem, type `B` is the type of the output problem and type `C` will probably be a boolean (the result type of the test for base case).

There is also other stuff, like the use of `async()` to compute concurrently the solution, but this is not the focus of my question.

My question is: why do I get the following message when I compile, complaining about **conflicting types** ?

```
D&C.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
D&C.cpp:67:92: error: no matching function for call to ‘divideAndConquer(std::string&, main(int, char**)::__lambda4&, main(int, char**)::__lambda5&, main(int, char**)::__lambda6&, main(int, char**)::__lambda7&)’
     divideAndConquer(text, lambda_basecase, lambda_divide, lambda_conquer, lambda_solvecase);
                                                                                            ^
D&C.cpp:67:92: note: candidate is:
D&C.cpp:10:3: note: template<class A, class B, class C> B divideAndConquer(A, C, A, B, B)
 B divideAndConquer(const A x, C basecase, A divide, B conquer, B solvecase)
   ^
D&C.cpp:10:3: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
D&C.cpp:67:92: note:   deduced conflicting types for parameter ‘A’ (‘std::basic_string<char>’ and ‘main(int, char**)::__lambda5’)
     divideAndConquer(text, lambda_basecase, lambda_divide, lambda_conquer, lambda_solvecase);
```

The Code is the following: basically the idea is to use the Divide and Conquer procedure to look for the instances of a target string into a text, but to be general enough to reuse this schema to solve also other problems (e.g. the Fibonacci numbers).

```c
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <future>

using namespace std;

template <typename A, typename B, typename C>
B divideAndConquer(const A x, C basecase, A divide, B conquer, B solvecase)
{
    if (basecase(x))
    return solvecase(x);

    A probl1 = divide(x,1);
    A probl2 = divide(x, 2);

    auto sol1f = async(divideAndConquer, probl1, basecase, divide, conquer, solvecase);
    B sol2 = divideAndConquer(probl2, basecase, divide, conquer, solvecase);
    B sol1 = sol1f.get();

    return (conquer(sol1, sol2));
}

int splitOnWhitespaces(const string& text, int half, string direction){
    int i=half, N = text.length();
    if (direction.compare("forward")==0){    
        while(text[i]!=' ' && text[i] != '\n' && i < N)
            i++;
    }
    else{
         while(text[i]!=' ' && text[i] != '\n' && i >= 0)
            i--;
    if (i<=0 || i==N)
        return -1;
    else
        return i;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    string text= "Nel mezzo del cammin di nostra vita mi ritrovai per una selva oscura, che la diritta via era smarrita.";
    string target = "nel";
    int base = 10;
    auto lambda_basecase = [base](string text){return text.length()<=base;};
    auto lambda_divide= [](string text, int subprobl){
         int half = text.length()/2;
         half = splitOnWhitespaces(text, half, "forward");
         if (half==-1)
            half = splitOnWhitespaces(text, half, "backward");
         if (half==-1)
             throw runtime_error("Error splitting the string: no whitespaces\n");
         return ((subprobl==1) ? string(text, 0, half) : string(text, half));
     };
    auto lambda_conquer = [](int count1, int count2){return count1+count2;};    
    auto lambda_solvecase = [target](string baseText){
        int found = 0;
        int start = 0;
        int len = target.length();
        while(baseText.find(target, start)!=string::npos ){
            found++;
            int position = baseText.find(target, start);
            start = position + len + 1;
        }
        return found;
    };
    divideAndConquer(text, lambda_basecase, lambda_divide, lambda_conquer, lambda_solvecase);
    return 0;
}
```

I am studying template programming right now, so any help about this issue and any reference to (good) books or webpages explaining the matter would be appreciated.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you mean to write `const std::string x` instead of `const A x`? Otherwise the types of parameters don't match (If so, we should close as typo). btw `const std::string& x` might be a better choice.

Comment: There are many typographical errors here, so I'm voting to close. You seem to get your template types mixed up with other types. At the same time, I want to help you without posting an answer, so I've mocked up something that will *compile* [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/N24l4R9dFmchvQMw). Note, you likely have logic errors, too.

Comment: You expect 1st and 3rd argument of divideAndConquer function to share the type (except from const), but passing std::string and lambda. Those have different types, resulting in lack of match.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, a suggestion: give names to template type that are more useful (that suggest the use) than `A`, `B`, `C`, ...

So become more understandable that you have given the same type identifier to completely different things (`A` for `std::string` and for a lambda function; `B` for two different lambda types (and take in count that different lambda are ever different types; also when with the same signature) and for the return value (`int`, in your example)).

I propose the following version

```
template <typename dataT, typename divT, typename conqT, typename baseT,
          typename solvT>
auto divideAndConquer (dataT const & x, baseT basecase, divT divide,
                       conqT conquer, solvT solvecase)
   -> decltype(solvecase(x))
 {
   using retT = decltype(solvecase(x));

   if ( basecase(x) )
      return solvecase(x);

   dataT const probl1 { divide(x, 1) };
   dataT const probl2 { divide(x, 2) };

   auto sol1f = async<retT(*)(dataT const &, baseT, divT, conqT, solvT)>
      (divideAndConquer, probl1, basecase, divide, conquer, solvecase);

   retT sol2 { divideAndConquer(probl2, basecase, divide, conquer,
                                solvecase) };
   retT sol1 { sol1f.get() };

   return conquer(sol1, sol2);
 }
```